# Reading books in public, copyright

Tags: copyright

Can you read, not aloud, copyrighted material eg. Books, scientific papers in public eg bus, airplane, cafe,  where other people can potentially read it/take picture?

Answer (score 3):

Of course. Copyright law prevents you from making copies, and prevents others from making copies. It doesn’t oblige you to take extreme precautions against vague possibilities that others might break the law.

And reading is not considered “copying”. So you don’t have to prevent others from reading your books at all.

Comment: @ohwilleke By a strict enough reading of the law, it would be illegal to even carry the book without covering it up, because you'd be "displaying" the cover artwork.

Comment: So it is is illegal by strict adherence?

Comment: @DM I missed the "not aloud" part of the question with sloppy reading.

Comment: @ohwilleke Don't feel bad; so did I. I think my mind removed the "not". Or else it got edited; edits right after the question is posted aren't always shown in the edit history.